# Apache SOLR indexing not working after data import successfull

Tags: mysql, solr, dataimporthandler, sunspot-solr, solr5

i am implementing solr for our ecommerce search functionality and i am running solr.war in jboss, solr home is in different directory path. i have configured my db-data-config.xml to map mysql database

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees"
            user="root"
            password="admin" /> 


  <document name="ecomm">

    <entity name="employees" query="select emp_no, first_name, last_name from employees limit 2000">
        <field name="emp_no" column="EMP_NO" />
        <field name="first_name" column="FIRST_NAME" />
        <field name="last_name" column="LAST_NAME" />
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

when i do full-import , all 2000 records are getting imported , but it is not getting indexed. so when i query it

```
Requests: 1 (1/s), Fetched: 2,000 (2,000/s), Skipped: 0, Processed: 0 (0/s)
    http://localhost:8080/solr/employees/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"*:*",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

where as when i tweak my query , and add alias "id", the id is getting  `processed` , ie indexed

```
 Requests: 1, Fetched: 2,000, Skipped: 0, Processed: 2,000
query="select emp_no as 'id', first_name , last_name from employees limit 2000"
```

and getting only 'id' data while quering.

```
 "response": {
    "numFound": 2000,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "10001",
        "_version_": 1501167564520161300
      },
```

EDIT :- Adding database schema screenshot [image: db schema]

Comment: What does your schema look like? Are there fields for emp_no, first_name and last_name present? Have you tried making sure that you use the same case in the query as the field="" definitions?

Comment: @MatsLindh yeah  i have same fields in the db schema, also i have attached the screenshot for your reference

Comment: I was thinking about Solrs schema :-)

Comment: yeah i have fixed, i didnt add the fields in the schema, after adding it , it worked. <dynamicField name="*_name"  type="text_general"   multiValued="false" indexed="true"  stored="true" />